# User-Group relation in mongodb

Tags: typescript, mongodb, next.js, prisma

I'm learning Next.js, and in my current project, I use both Prisma and MongoDB. In my project a user can belong to only one group, and the group can have several members. However, after a user creates a group, the user doesn't show up in the members list when I check the database on mongodb.com.

My schema

```
model User {
  id            String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name          String?
  email         String?   @unique
  password      String?
  emailVerified DateTime?
  image         String?
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]
  bio           String?
  phone         String?
  picturePath   String?
  groupId       String?   @map("groupId") @db.ObjectId
  createdGroup  Group?    @relation("created")
  memberOfGroup Group?    @relation("members", fields: [groupId], references: [id])

  @@map("users")
}

model Group {
  id          String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name        String
  description String
  owner       User   @relation("created", references: [id], fields: [ownerId], onUpdate: NoAction)
  ownerId     String @unique @db.ObjectId
  members     User[] @relation("members")

  @@map("groups")
}
```

Group action

```
"use server";

import { Session } from "next-auth";
import { prisma } from "../db/prisma";

interface CreateGroupProps {
  session: Session | null;
  data: {
    name: string;
    description: string;
  };
}

export async function createGroup({
  session,
  data,
}: CreateGroupProps): Promise<void> {
  if (!session?.user?.id) {
    throw new Error("User ID is missing.");
  }

  try {
    const newGroup = await prisma.group.create({
      data: {
        name: data.name,
        description: data.description,
        ownerId: session.user.id,
        members: {
          connect: {
            id: session.user.id,
          },
        },
      },
    });
    await prisma.user.update({
      where: {
        id: session.user.id,
      },
      data: {
        groupId: newGroup.id,
      },
    });
    console.log(newGroup);
  } catch (error: any) {
    throw new Error(`Failed to create group: ${error.message}`);
  }
}
```

Button

```
"use client";

import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { Session } from "next-auth";

interface ButtonProps {
  session: Session | null;
  data: any;
  action: (props: any) => void;
  label: string;
}

function SharedButton({ session, data, action, label }: ButtonProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <Button
        className="bg-primary-500"
        onClick={() => action({ session, data })}
      >
        {label}
      </Button>
    </>
  );
}

export default SharedButton;
```

I tried using the console log to find out what data is being sent and it looks fine

```
{
{
  id: '650ee61d119ce43c70d710b2',
  name: 'asdad',
  description: 'dddddd',
  ownerId: '6508c7819ce58cceec142343',
  members: [
    {
      id: '6508c7819ce58cceec142343',
      name: 'Test',
      email: 'Test@gmail.com',
      password: null,
      emailVerified: null,
      image: 'data:...',
      bio: 'testdddd',
      phone: '123456789072',
      picturePath: null,
      groupId: '650ee61d119ce43c70d710b2'
    }
  ]
}
```

Is this an error in my  prismaschema or in createGroup?

Comment: Have you tried `connect: [ { id: session.user.id } ]` instead of  `connect: { id: session.user.id }` ?

Comment: Yes, still not working :/